# how to call T20 Image gallery from UITableView

Tags: iphone

i have a list of image categories in a tableview. i want to load the specific category of images when the user selects a category from the tableview. i know that it should be inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but dont know which method to call from didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push a new view controller and send your image array to that view controller. Then use that array to create the three20 gallery. Simple!

Comment: But when push the new viewcontroller, the three20 gallery loses its property of being backtranslucent. i tried a lot but cant set it back to blacktranslucent. please help!